# When loading an html file through LoadFromResource that has javascript files defined in the html the javascript fails to execute inside of C++

Tags: javascript, html, c++

So the basics of the project that I'm working on are as follows:
I've got my main application that is coded in C++ and this is where I have created a class that utilizes CHtmlView; I've called the class CHtmlEditor.

Inside of CHtmlEditor I have a function defined below

```
BOOL CHtmlEditor::CreateHtmlEditor(CRect rRectHtml, CWnd* wParentWindow, DWORD dwStyle, UINT id)
{
    BOOL bRetVal = CHtmlView::Create(NULL, "HTML Editor", dwStyle, rRectHtml, wParentWindow, id);

    LoadFromResource(_T("HTMLEDITORFRAME.HTML"));

    return bRetVal;
}
```

This does work. The html file is loaded
However I have two javascripts files defined inside of the html file using the script tags and when I try to access the functions in that javascript from inside of the C++ the function fails to execute

Here's what the head of my html file looks like:

```
<head>
    <link href="htmleditor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
```

To execute my javascript inside of my C++ I have a function that's defined below

```
bool CHtmlEditor::CallJScript(IDispatch* pDocument, const CString strFunc, const CStringArray& paramArray, CComVariant& vOut)
{
    CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pHtmlDoc = pDocument;
    if (pHtmlDoc == NULL)
        ...

    //Getting Java Script object
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spScript;
    HRESULT hr = pHtmlDoc->get_Script(&spScript);
    ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr) || spScript == NULL)
        ...

    //Find dispid for given function in the object
    CComBSTR bstrMember(strFunc);
    DISPID dispid = NULL;
    hr = spScript->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &bstrMember, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CT2A ascii(strFunc);
        std::string strFunc2 = ascii.m_psz;
        ...
    }

    const int arraySize = paramArray.GetSize();

    //Putting parameters
    DISPPARAMS dispparams;
    memset(&dispparams, 0, sizeof dispparams);
    dispparams.cArgs = arraySize;
    dispparams.rgvarg = new VARIANT[dispparams.cArgs];
    dispparams.cNamedArgs = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        CComBSTR bstr = paramArray.GetAt(arraySize - 1 - i); // back reading
        bstr.CopyTo(&dispparams.rgvarg[i].bstrVal);
        dispparams.rgvarg[i].vt = VT_BSTR;
    }

    EXCEPINFO excepInfo;
    memset(&excepInfo, 0, sizeof excepInfo);
    UINT nArgErr = (UINT)-1;  // initialize to invalid arg

    //Call JavaScript function
    hr = spScript->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, 0,
        DISPATCH_METHOD, &dispparams,
        & vOut, &excepInfo, &nArgErr);

    delete[] dispparams.rgvarg;

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CT2A ascii(strFunc);
        std::string strFunc2 = ascii.m_psz;
        ...
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there something specific that needs to be done to utilize the javascript that's defined inside of the html?